# Userdefaults has no member standarduserdefaults in Swift3

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, swift3

Type 'UserDefaults' has no member 'StandardUserDefaults'

This is Swift 3.

Here is the game view controller

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var darkswitch: UISwitch!

    @IBOutlet var lightswitch: UISwitch!

    var DarkOn = Bool()

    var LightOn = Bool()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        if (DarkOn == true){
            darkswitch.isOn = true
            lightswitch.isOn = false

        }

        if (lightswitch == true){
            darkswitch.isOn = false
            lightswitch.isOn = true

        }




        if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView

            skView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            ˚
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate : Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.allButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    @IBAction func darkaction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        darkswitch.isOn = true
        lightswitch.isOn = false

        var darkdefault = UserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults()
        darkdefault.setBool(true,forKey: "darkdefault")


        var lightdefault = UserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults()

        lightdefault.setBool (false, forkey: "lightdefault")

    }


    @IBAction func lightaction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        darkswitch.isOn = false
        lightswitch.isOn = true

        var darkdefault = UserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults()
        darkdefault.setBool(false,forKey: "darkdefault")


        var lightdefault = UserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults()

        lightdefault.setBool (true, forkey: "lightdefault")
    }



    override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: It's now called `UserDefaults.standard`.

Comment: `if (lightswitch == true){` Is redundant. You can write `if lightswitch {`

Comment: It is Swift convention to name all your variables starting with lowercase letters.

Comment: You just need one UserDefaults.standard object

Comment: Just so you know, "ASAP" [doesn't go down very well here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is now

```
 UserDefaults.standard.
```